# Error to parse the url value using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing the url using regex. Some urls is not showing completely. I am using the following code.

it is working if the $string value is following

```
$string= "[video width="1280" height="720" mp4="http://egghead-site.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/DOS.mp4" title="DOS Software"][/video]" ;
```

if the mp4 value is following then it is not working. it is returning the half url only.

```
$string =[video width="1280" height="720" mp4="http://egghead-site.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/Colon%20Health%20Final%20V3.mp4" title="Synergi" ][/video]";  

$imageurl = !empty( $string ) ? preg_match_all('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', $string , $match) : '';

return isset($match[0][0]) ? ut_portfolio_add_http($match[0][0]) : '';
```

I wanna to get the video url. I am new in regex so that I stuck at this point. Please let me know how can I get it in both cases.

Comment: Please could you write an example code without syntax errors.

Comment: then how it is working for the first string ?

Comment: code is working but it shows the half url only http://egghead-site.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/Colon

Comment: @user3885484 No wonder, you have parts of it on a newline. Also your regex is far from matching an url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: This is a quick fix of your regex `((https?://)?([-\w%]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)` Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a small change to your regex and it seems to be picking up exactly what you want. See here:

```
((https?:\/\/)+(.+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)
```